# How to combine angle with pendulum's period?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, time

Does the period of [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) has something to do with the angle (with the situation where the pendulum was still)?
I have searched the internet but haven't found any satisfying answer.I have also determined a formula using angle but I just can't be sure if my formula is right. So anyone with the proof please come forward.
Try doing it by the law conservation of energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frequency of pendulum does not depend on the initial angle of deflection, when it is small. That is, if ideal pendulum in vacuum is deflected at an angle $\phi$, then let go, pendulum [will oscillate](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pend.html) with period $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$, where $L$ is length of the thread.

For large initial angle of deflection $\theta_0$, period [will depend](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pendl.html) on it as:

T=$2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}[1+ \frac{1}{16}\theta_0^2+ \frac{11}{3072}\theta_0^4+...]$

Comment: This is true only for the small angle approximation.

Comment: I don't want this small angle approximation. I want to what happen in bigger angle.

Comment: How did you get this???Can you show me please?

Comment: @aaaaaa How did you get that?can u show me or give me the link?